# How do I get 'sticky' code section behavior in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I saw this sticky code behavior in Visual Studio Code once: when the user scrolled their code, the section they were in remains locked at the top and the code is easier to read and make sense of:

[image]

Can someone tell me how can I do it? Or is there any extension for it?

Comment: Can you ask that "someone"?

Comment: @fildor I cannot ask that "someone"

Comment: search for `sticky scroll` setting

Comment: Line 14 on the screenshot, right editor.